# Number of flops in Gaussian Elimination Matlab code

Tags: matlab, time-complexity, linear-algebra, linear-equation, flops

I am having a hard time trying to understand why this Matlab code to perform Gaussian Elimination without pivoting using LU factorization takes `(2/3) * n^3` flops. (FLOPs: floating point operations and **not** FLOPS: floating point operations per second)

```
function x = GaussianElimination(A,b)

n = length(b);
for k = 1:n-1
    for i = k+1:n
        mult = A(i,k)/A(k,k);
        A(i,k+1:n) = A(i,k+1:n)-mult*A(k,k+1:n);
        b(i) = b(i) - mult*b(k);
    end
end

x = zeros(n,1);
x(n) = b(n)/A(n,n);

for k = n-1:-1:1
    x(k) = (b(k) - A(k,k+1:n)*x(k+1:n))/A(k,k);
end

end
```

If anyone could explain to me how flops are counted for those nested loops that start at `k+1` I would be grateful.

PS: I am not talking about algorithmic complexity here.

Comment: Are you talking about algorithmic complexity? My understanding of the term "flops" is as an acronym for "Floating point Operations Per Second", typically expressed in terms of megaflops, gigaflops, teraflops, etc.  But it appears here that you're asking about the complexity of the algorithm which I have never seen expressed in "flops".  ???

Comment: No, flops = floating point operations. This is why it is confusing me because it is not counted the same as algorithmic complexity.

Comment: Obviously computer science instructions has passed me by and my knowledge is no longer useful. Best of luck.

Comment: After some extra search it turns out that FLOPs and FLOPS are two different acronyms so I updated my question.

Comment: Yes, FLOPS is the number of floating point operations. See the bottom of [this old post](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matlab-incorporates-lapack.html) by MathWorks founder Cleve Moler. What is stated is even more true today with JIT acceleration. The question is if you want to count the true number of flops executed by your computer or the number that would be used by a a human manually implementing an algorithm such as Gaussian elimination

Comment: I am not even sure if the `(2/3) * n^3` flops is for a computer or a human but I would assume that it is for the human?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself.

FLOPs are counted a little different than algorithmic complexity in the sense that lower order terms are still ignored but the coefficient in front of the highest order term does matter.

In this specific example, since we ignore lower order terms, we only look at `+, -, *, /` operations in the triple nested loop and ignore other floating point operations in the rest of the algorithm. i.e. the following line

```
    A(i,k+1:n) = A(i,k+1:n)-mult*A(k,k+1:n);
```

- first loop runs from 1 to n
- second loop runs from k to n
- third loop runs from k to n (implicit in Matlab code with the use of `:`)

Thus, this line runs almost `n^3` times and precisely `n*n + (n-1)*(n-1) + ... + 2*2 + 1*1` times which is equivalent to `(1/3)*n^3` flops when ignoring lower order terms.

However, this line has two floating point operations: a `-` operation and a `*` operation.

Therefore, this gives `(2/3)*n^3`.